# Why Spark Dataframe functions' parameters (eg: groupby, select) are designed like (col1: String, cols: String*) instead of (cols: String*)?

Tags: apache-spark, design-patterns

In Spark, there are a batch of operators or functions like 'select', 'groupby','dropDuplicates'...

The parameters of those functions are always like (col1: String, cols: String*), eg:

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
  def dropDuplicates(col1: String, cols: String*): Dataset[T] = {
    val colNames: Seq[String] = col1 +: cols
    dropDuplicates(colNames)
  }

  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def groupBy(col1: String, cols: String*): RelationalGroupedDataset = {
    val colNames: Seq[String] = col1 +: cols
    RelationalGroupedDataset(
      toDF(), colNames.map(colName => resolve(colName)), RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupByType)
  }

  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame = select((col +: cols).map(Column(_)) : _*)
```

When the type of parameters is String, the functions are always defined as (col: String, cols: String*) instead of (cols: String*).

In every function, the first statement is always combining the two paras like "val colNames: Seq[String] = col1 +: cols", nothing more else.

**Considering that there is only one parameter if the type of parameters is Column. eg:**

```
  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def groupBy(cols: Column*): RelationalGroupedDataset = {
    RelationalGroupedDataset(toDF(), cols.map(_.expr), RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupByType)
  }

  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def select(cols: Column*): DataFrame = withPlan {
    Project(cols.map(_.named), logicalPlan)
  }
```

So I'm wondering why not using (cols: String*) instead of (col1: String, cols: String*)? It seems like (cols: String*) makes more sense like (cols: Column*)

Answer (score 1):

This practice dates back to Java. In the third edition of [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997) it's 
`Item53: Use varargs judiciously`.

> Sometimes it’s appropriate to write a method that requires *one* or more arguments of some type, rather than *zero* or more. For example, suppose you want to write a function that computes the minimum of its arguments. This function is not well defined if the client passes no arguments. You could check the array length at runtime [but] This solution has several problems. The most serious is that if the client invokes this method with no arguments, it fails at runtime rather than compile time.
>
> Luckily there’s a much better way to achieve the desired effect. Declare the method to take two parameters, one normal parameter of the specified type and one varargs parameter of this type. This solution corrects all the deficiencies of the previous one.

Of course that assumes you want to require at least *one* parameter. If your function can work with *zero*, then a single (varargs) parameter is fine.

Comment: why those methods are defined seperately with varise types of arguments. Use (cols: Column*) for the Column type , use (col1: String, cols: String*) for the String type.

Comment: like select, groupby those common methods